# The Space Between Atoms And Sub-Atomic Particles And More

Tags: particle-physics, atoms, vacuum, quantum-chemistry, subatomic

I was wondering what the space between atoms or electrons is called. Is it Vacuum ? And what is in there ? Is it really free or empty space ? And if so, how can nothing exist ? It is a bit of an odd yet simple question so I will put it aside.

All I want to know is - **what is the space between atoms etc. is called and what does it consist of ?**

And also, additionally, I want to know how (are) Electrons are Exchanged (for conductance of electricity etc.) when they are said to be only moving around in their defined orbits .(?)
Do they simply move out of their orbits and jump into another atom when they come in contact ?

And also, *how come or can an Electron one element (A) move to another element (B) which is different from the first element (A) ? Doesn't electrons etc. make up the properties of that particular element ?*

I don't want to go in as deep as quarks etc. but I will like to know the answer for this since quarks will be too small and if we have reached that level, we must (be) know(ing) what is on the higher level, or perhaps superficial suits better.

And have we seem electrons and protons ? I have seen videos of electrons perhaps but they more like a simulation I think. One video for Hydrogen atom is available which seems real and legit video (not sure) seen through the device used.
But can we not simply attach a camera to a microscope (or the equipment used) at a certain angle to get a better view and take pictures and record videos of those ?
And have Scientists themselves actually seen quarks and such smaller particles ? And were those coloured (in colour) or not ?

Thank You !

Comment: There are far too many confused questions here. Please ask a *single, focused question* per post.

Comment: It's called "space", like everywhere else. It's filled with the same "stuff" that it's filled with everywhere else: the fields of the "physical vacuum". Electrons and other "particles" are really just local properties of the fields of the physical vacuum. They don't exist independently of the fields and it's not a good idea to imagine them "moving" around. When we make measurements on these fields we either find an electron somewhere or we don't. If we don't, we simply don't know "where" it is. It doesn't even make sense to talk about "it" being somewhere else.

Comment: I count at least 13 questions there. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: CuriousOne, yes, I can recall now that for electricity, some kind of field or special interactive force exerting area is created by the means of which electricity is generated and so the particles aren't themselves interacting, but their created fields are. Thank You for that ! 

But I am sorry I couldn't understand what you meant. Can you please explain - Particles are really just local properties 'of the fields'.  I thought that the fields were created by the electrons themselves and not the "space" between them. Or is it that both of them create a field ?

Comment: A note to those who try to end a post like this - Please, don't mark this as unclear etc. simply because there are more than one question.  The ones who have to answer, answer regardless of how many questions there are and they provide the answer for what they know. I clearly 'highlight' what is important and major in the question. And besides, you people are humans and not so stupid I assume, so I think you can understand what is written and act accordingly, but in a more constructive and helpful way. What THIS does is simply restrain me from using StackExchange. Do try to be more polite.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on your first question. According to my readings in quantum  mechanics , this vacuum is full of virtuall particles and antiparticles that borrow energy from vacuum and live for a tiny fraction of time and then vanish.